Animated film where obese man eats the world
I'm trying to identify an animated short from the late 1970's or early 1980's. I believe it was part of an anthology-style movie in the vein of "Tales from the Crypt" or some such, but I could be wrong. The art style was similar to the first Heavy Metal movie in 1981, but it isn't part of that. It aired on cable, but I'm not sure which network/channel it was. Mostly likely HBO or Showtime. 
The part I'm trying to identify is the following:

An obese man in a white suit sitting down to eat at a fancy restaurant. 
As he eats more and more food, he grows larger, eventually consuming the Earth itself. 
If I remember Correctly, he ends up devouring all of reality but then it turns out to be a nightmare fueled by indigestion or something.


Not exactly as you described, but Hunger from 1974 has similar themes and you can watch it on youtube (linked above) to confirm.

@BryanTurriff - not what I'm looking for, but I definitely think drugs were involved in the creation of both.

One of the comments on the Hunger YouTube video thanked the animators for sparing him having to trip on acid.

Would it be Big Eater at all?
